# Understanding indexed view update qnd query process in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, sql-server-2008-r2, indexed

I created indexed view (clustered unique index on `Table1_ID`) view with such T-SQL:

```
Select Table1_ID, Count_BIG(*) as Table2TotalCount from Table2 inner join
Table1 inner join... where Table2_DeletedMark=0 AND ... Group BY Table1_ID
```

Also after creating the view, we set clustered unique index on column Table1_ID.
So View consists of two columns:

```
Table1_ID
Table2TotalCount
```

T-Sql for creating View is a heavy because of group by and several millions of rows in Table2.

But when I run a query to a view like

```
Select Total2TotalCount from MyView where Table1_ID = k
```

- it executes fast and without overhead for server.

Also in t-sql for creating view many conditions in where clause for `Table2` columns. And
If I changed Table2_DeletedMark to 1 and run a query

```
Select Total2TotalCount from MyView where Table1_ID = k
```

again - I'll get correct results. (`Table2TotalCount` decreased by 1).

**So our questions are:**
1. Why does query execution time decreased so much when we used Indexed View (compare to without view using (even we run `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS()` before executing query to VIEW))
2. After changing

```
Table2_DeletedMark
```

View immediately recalculated and we get correct results, but what is the process behind? we can't imagine that  sql executes t-sql by what view was generated each time we changes any values of 10+ columns containing in the t-sql view generating,  because it is too heavy.
We understand that it is enough to run a simple query to recalculate values, depends on columns values we changing.
But how does sql understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indexed view is **materialized** e.g. its rows that it contains (from the tables it depends on) are **physically stored** on disk - much like a "system-computed" table that's always kept up to date whenever its underlying tables change. This is done by adding the clustered index - the leaf pages of the clustered index on a SQL Server table (or view) **are** the data pages, really.

Columns in an indexed view can be indexed with non-clustered indexes, too, and thus you can improve query performance even more. The down side is: since the rows are stored, you need disk space (and some data is duplicated, obviously).

A normal view on the other hand is just a fragment of SQL that will be executed to compute the results - based on what you select from that view. There's no physical representation of that view, there are no rows stored for a regular view - they need to be joined together from the base tables as needed.

Comment: I understand that indexed view is materialized. The main question is our second question. I wonder a mechanism that works for "always kept up to date whenever its underlying tables change.". How it works ? Can you explain due to question 2

Comment: @mmcteam.com.au: other than someone from the SQL Server team, I don't think anyone can really explain in detail how this works. I just know for a fact that it does work - the indexed view is updated whenever any of the underlying tables are changed. That's all I need to know myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think there are so many bizarre rules on what's allowed in indexed views, and what the base tables are allowed to do? It's so that the SQL engine can immediately know "If I'm touching this row, it potentially affects the result of this view - let's see, this row no longer fits the view criteria, but I insisted on having a COUNT_BIG(*), so I can just decrement that value by one"